# Assign existing node as translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Is there a possibility to assign existing nodes as translation of a node?

Cause i migrated a lot of content from a D6 instance. On D6 and D7, it was easy to assign the translation nodes but in D8 it seems not to have that possibility.
I also didn't found any modules which helps.

Any advice?

Comment: No, you can not. You have to migrate the separate D6 nodes into the same D8 node. Which the migrations should now do by default.